# A better (top ranked) model has a much higher deviance in AIC model selection

Tags: model-selection, aic, deviance

I have the same number of parameters for the top model but a much higher deviance for that model than some of the lower-ranked models. I don't have any missing values for any of my variables, no change in sample size between models, and I don't get any errors for model convergence when I'm running them. The differences in deviances between some of the models are very high (ex 500 vs 160). I'm not sure what's going on. Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image]

Comment: Show us these models.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.